# Informix connection disappearing from Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, database-connection, informix

I'm connecting to an Informix database from a Rails app, and there are times where the app will die (requiring a restart it seems), with the following error message:

```
Informix::DatabaseError: Connection does not exist: SELECT first 300 blah from ...
```

This app runs in an environment with plenty of firewalls and network switches, and I'm sure there's something out there which is forcefully killing off connections that remain open for a long period of time.

In most connection pools I've used in Java, there are ways to give test SQL to run before handing out a connection to the pool, setting the max time a connection could be open, how long one should be idle, etc.  Are there ways to define these settings in a Rails app?

If it matters, here's some version #s of gems that seem to be associated with this issue:

```
Using activerecord (3.0.7) 
Using ruby-informix (0.7.3) 
Using activerecord-informix-adapter (1.1.1) 
Using activeresource (3.0.7) 
Using rails (3.0.7)
```

Comment: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-1203optimizeinformix/